# Translating a Set of Integers to String Values in SQL Server( Using T-SQL for certain and maybe .NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net, t-sql

I have multiple tables that have int values in them that represent a specific string (Text) and I want to convert the integers to the string values.  The goal is to make a duplicate copy of the table and then translate the integers to strings for easy analysis.

For example, I have the animalstable and the AnimalType Field consists of int values.

0 = "Cat", 1 = dog, 2= "bird", 3 = "turtle", 99 = "I Don't Know"

Can someone help me out with some starting code for this translation to animalsTable2 showing the string values?

Any help would be so very much appreciated!  I want to thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: We aren't here to write code for you. Get started yourself, and when you run into a specific issue come back and ask us for help. [See this article on how to ask a good question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Adam thank you for the pointers.  This was my first question ever and I didn't have another resource to reach out for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to create a related table that defines the integer values.

```
CREATE TABLE [Pets](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Pet] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pets] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then you can insert your pet descriptions but you can leave out the "I don't Know" item; it can be handled by left joining the Pets table to your main table.

--0 = "Cat", 1 = dog, 2= "bird", 3 = "turtle", 99 = "I Don't Know"`

```
INSERT INTO [Pets] ([ID],[Pet]) VALUES(0, 'cat');
INSERT INTO [Pets] ([ID],[Pet]) VALUES(1, 'dog');
INSERT INTO [Pets] ([ID],[Pet]) VALUES(2, 'bird');
INSERT INTO [Pets] ([ID],[Pet]) VALUES(3, 'turtle');
```

Now you can include the [Pets].[Descr] field in the output of your query like so

```
SELECT [MainTableFiled1]
,[MainTableFieldx]
,isnull([Pet], 'I dont know') as Pet
FROM [dbo].[MainTable] a
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Pets] b
ON a.[MainTable_PetID] = b.[ID]
```

Alternatively, you can just define the strings in a case statement inside you query.  This however, is not advised if you could be using the strings in more than one query.

```
Select case SomeField
        when 0 then 'cat'
        when 1 then 'dog'
        when 2 then 'bird'
        when 3 then 'turtle'
        else 'i dont know' end as IntToString
from SomeTable
```

The benefit of the related table is you have only one place to maintain your string definitions and any edits would propagate to all queries, views or procedures that use it.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Understood - your criticism is appreciated and well taken.  I add some context as you requested and I'll make this a habit.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table to store the mappings. Then insert from a join between that table and the original table like so:

```
-- Create temp table
DECLARE @animalMapping TABLE(
    animalType int NOT NULL,
    animalName varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

-- Insert values into temp table
INSERT INTO @animalMapping (animalType, animalName) 
   VALUES (0, 'Cat'), 
          (1, 'Dog'), 
          (2, 'Bird'), 
          (3, 'Turtle'),
          (99, 'I don''t know');

-- Insert into new table
INSERT INTO animalsTable2
  SELECT id, <other fields from animalstable>,
        @animalMapping.animalName
  FROM animalstable
  JOIN @animalMapping
        ON animalstable.AnimalType = @animalMapping.animalType
```

Comment: bsivel and bpruitt-goddard I want to thank you both for answering my question with code snippets.  I have 100's of fields to do this to and needed help getting started on this.  Thank you so much!